# Buscador que Consulta de dos tablas diferentes laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

**Descripición**
El buscador actualmente hace una consulta a la tabla de noticias donde encuentra los datos por(*noticiero_programa, noticiero_turno, noticiero_fecha*),la pregunta es ¿Cómo se puede hacer que en esa misma consulta se extraigan los datos de la otra tabla que se llama notas? para despues mostrar los resultados en la vista.

**Tablas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modelos
Tabla nota**

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nota extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre_nota', 'editor_nota','duracion_nota', 'bloque_nota', 'noticia_id'];

    public function noticias()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\noticia', 'noticia_id');
        // pertenece a

    }




}
```

**Modelo tabla noticia**

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Noticia extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['noticiero_programa','noticiero_turno','noticiero_fecha'];

    public function notas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\nota', 'noticia_id');
        // tiene muchos
    }




}
```

**Vista de busqueda**

```html
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">Buscar</div>
  <form action="/noticia/buscar" method="get" onsubmit="return showLoad()">
  <div class="panel-body">
   <label class="label-control">Buscar</label>
   <input type="text" name="noticiero_turno" class="form-control" placeholder="Please input stock name/description" required="required">
   <br>

 </div>
 <div class="panel-footer">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
 </div>
 </form>
</div>
@if (isset($noticia))
   <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">Resultado de busqueda</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

     <div class='table-responsive'>
       <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Turno</th>
             <th>Fecha</th>

          <th>nombre_nota</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
     @foreach($noticia as $buscar)
     <tr>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_programa']}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_turno']}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>

      <tr/>






       @endforeach

    </tbody>




   </table>
<center>{{ $noticia->appends(Request::only('noticiero_turno'))->links() }}</center>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="{{url('noticia/buscar')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Reiniciar busqueda</a>
  </div>
</div>
@endif

@stop
```

Grafico de la vista del buscador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controlador del buscador**

```html
public function busqueda(Request $request)
{

  $ntc_turno = $request->input('noticiero_turno');
  if($ntc_turno){
    $noticia = Noticia::where('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
    ->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
    ->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")

    ->paginate(2);

    return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
  }else{
    $noticia = Noticia::paginate(3);
    return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tiene una relacion definida puedes utiliar `with` para traer los datos de la relacion, de la siguiente manera:

```
$noticia = Noticia::with('notas')->get();// notas es el nombre de la relación de que tienes en tu modelo Noticias.
```

Pero hay ocaciones donde necesitamos un consultar a la tabla de la relación.

Entonces podemos utilizar `with` como un array.

```
$data='2:30';
$noticia = Noticia::with(['notas'=>function($query)use($data){
    $query->where('nombre_nota',"Una nota")->where('duracion_nota',$data);
}])->get();
```

La parte del `use ($data)` es opcional, solo si necesitas datos externos.

Ahora el acceso a los datos seran de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($noticias as $noti){
    echo $noti->noticiero_programa;
    foreach($noti->notas as $notas){
        echo $noti->nombre_nota;
    }
}
```